# RegEx for replacing digits in the middle of alphanumeric strings but not at the end

Tags: python, regex

I have the following strings:

```
aaaaaaa0aaa
bbbbbbb0bbbbbb
cccccc 2.0
```

I need to replace the 0 in the middle of the first 2 strings with some character such as "x". If i use the regular expression `r'[0].'` then "0a" and "0b" gets selected from the first 2 strings. How i can i just select only "0" from the first 2 strings while avoiding the "0" in the last string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\B` to assert non-word-boundaries around a matching `0`:

```
\B0\B
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8GGONp/1

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''aaaaaaa0aaa
... bbbbbbb0bbbbbb
... cccccc 2.0'''
>>> print(re.sub(r'\B0\B', 'x', s))
aaaaaaaxaaa
bbbbbbbxbbbbbb
cccccc 2.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can collect our letters, then hold one letter as a left boundary of the digits we wish to replace, then another letter after digits just for safety, and continue capturing our end of string letters, and finally replace the digits with `$1x$3`:

```
(.+[a-z])([0-9]+)([a-z].+)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/UnnlXF/1/)

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UnnlXF/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(.+[a-z])([0-9]+)([a-z].+)"

test_str = ("aaaaaaa0aaa\n"
    "bbbbbbb0bbbbbb\n"
    "cccccc 2.0")

subst = "\\1x\\3"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /(.+[a-z])([0-9]+)([a-z].+)/gm;
const str = `aaaaaaa0aaa
bbbbbbb0bbbbbb
cccccc 2.0`;
const subst = `$1x$3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, but i was looking for something like the accepted answer. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

A simple positive lookahead as in `r'0(?=.)'` would suffice. Using python

```
import re

s = '''aaaaaaa0aaa
bbbbbbb0bbbbbb
cccccc 2.0'''

re.sub(pattern=r'0(?=.)', string=s, repl='x')

Out[743]: '\n    aaaaaaaxaaa\n    bbbbbbbxbbbbbb\n    cccccc 2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how greedy you want to be. Stricter is better, but something like this `[a-zA-Z](0)[a-zA-Z]` works fine assuming you always want to target `0` and it will be explicitly surrounded by an alpha character (a-zA-Z).

You can play around with it and see it working here: https://regex101.com/r/0UYSvp/1

Answer (score 0):

Just match anything after a 0: `0(.)` and replace with `x$1`

It will only match a zero if it has a character after it, and will replace it with "x" and that character.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YsRTRa/1) solution